# Multiple MKMapView 's causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, exc-bad-access, xcode7-beta5

My app has a need to implement a map in two seperate `UIViewController`'s, the problem is that once one of the maps has been rendered, trying to open the second causes a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error that shows at the declaration of AppDelegate, I have tried using Zombies and it shows nothing, tried Analyzing, again shows nothing, I have tried presenting the maps in a variety of ways, Including: programatically `presentViewController()`, as well as having a mapkit in each .storyboard and using containerViews that embed a map.storyboard which only contains a mapkit.

typing bt in the console gives me this:

> libglInterpose.dylib`EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int, id) + 204, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN, address=0x69725659)

Im using Xcode7-Beta5 and Swift, any help other possible debug methods, or some way to manage the maps more efficiently, would be greatly appreciated.

**MapViewController.swift** (Doesn't do anything yet, since i can't get them to both render)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

ok, so the hierarchy goes somewhat like this:

I have a `UITabBarController`, one of the tabs is a map, from another tab there is a view hierarchy that eventually leads to a button that presents another map.

I was able to get both maps rendering by placing my instance of Map.storyboard within my TabBarController subclass, then using `UIContainerView`s on both my `UIViewController`s that should have the map and adding a child ViewController (map from TabBarController) and its view to the ViewContainer

Comment: Can you post some code with that?

Comment: @sloik Posted the code for the MapViewController, but it doesnt do anything yet, I'm not able to get the two seperate maps rendering

Comment: I have just built a test application using the above code and a storyboard using Xcode 7 Beta 6. I have a navigation controller as the root controller and a segue between two different view controllers with maps on. Maybe try updating your local Xcode to Beta 6 to see if that fixes it?

Comment: thanks @JohnWordsworth ill grab it right now and see what happens

Comment: @JohnWordsworth unfortunately updating to xcode7-beta6 did not resolve the issue

Comment: Hmmm, then I'm afraid we might need more steps / clearer information about your setup to reproduce. I have setup an app with the following Storyboard and the same MapViewController you provided above and it works fine on iOS and the Simulator. Is your case any different to this? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rfBgD3wC3_RjVrb1M4cjBGVGs

Comment: Is mapView connected on both controllers? If instead of using `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!` you use `var mapView = MKMapView()`. Do the crashes still happen?

Comment: @JohnWordsworth my case is a bit different, i have a tabbar, 1 of the tabs is a map, and another tab presents a UIImagepicker, then an "UploadVC" which has a button to present another map

Comment: ok, guys thanks for all your help! Ive made some progress, and edited my question